# How to toggle 2 classes and set a cookie after each toggle?

Tags: jquery

On clicking of a button, I want three things to happen, a slideToggle, toggle between 2 classes, and a setting of a cookie.  I have the first two things working properly, I now need to set a cookie of `companyDescriptionDiv` to be either `opened` or `closed` depending on whether `#showhide-company-description` has a class of opened or closed

```
$(document).on('click', "#showhide-company-description", function () {
    $("#companydescription").slideToggle("slow", function () {
        $("#showhide-company-description").toggleClass("opened").toggleClass("closed");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Btw you don't have to call toggleClass twice, you can pass a comma separated list of classes to toggle, e.g. toggleClass('opened, closed'). Personally I'd do it like this:

```
$(document).on('click', "#showhide-company-description", function () {
    var $toggler = $(this);
    $("#companydescription").slideToggle("slow", function () {
        var isOpen = $toggler.toggleClass('opened, closed').hasClass('opened');
        if(isOpen) {
            setCookie.routine();
        });
    });
});
```

This will execute the toggle and return its "state" at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Check the class:

```
if ($("#showhide-company-description").hasClass("opened")) {
  //set cookie
}
```

[Set cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)

Comment: I didn't want to do an if, I was hoping there was some way to to intercept the setting of the classes, e.g. ....toggleClass("opened",function(){)